# Python: Object does not support indexing

Tags: python, object, indexing, typeerror

Yes, this question has been asked before. No, none of the answers I read could fix the problem I have.

I'm trying to create a little Bounce game. I've created the bricks like this:

```
def __init__(self,canvas):
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.brick1 = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,50,20,fill=random_fill_colour(),outline=random_fill_colour())
    self.brick2 = canvas.create_rectangle(50,0,100,20,fill=random_fill_colour(),outline=random_fill_colour())
    self.brick3 = canvas.create_rectangle(100,0,150,20,fill=random_fill_colour(),outline=random_fill_colour())
    self.brick4 = canvas.create_rectangle(150,0,200,20,fill=random_fill_colour(),outline=random_fill_colour())
    self.brick5 = canvas.create_rectangle(200,0,250,20,fill=random_fill_colour(),outline=random_fill_colour())
    self.brick6 = canvas.create_rectangle(250,0,300,20,fill=random_fill_colour(),outline=random_fill_colour())
    self.brick7 = canvas.create_rectangle(300,0,350,20,fill=random_fill_colour(),outline=random_fill_colour())
    self.brick8 = canvas.create_rectangle(350,0,400,20,fill=random_fill_colour(),outline=random_fill_colour())
    self.brick9 = canvas.create_rectangle(400,0,450,20,fill=random_fill_colour(),outline=random_fill_colour())
    self.brick10 = canvas.create_rectangle(450,0,500,20,fill=random_fill_colour(),outline=random_fill_colour())
    self.bricksId = [self.brick1,self.brick2,self.brick3,self.brick4,self.brick5,self.brick6,self.brick7,self.brick8,self.brick9,self.brick10]
```

And I'm trying to reference the ID of `bricksId[0]` over here:

```
self.hit_brick(pos,self.bricks.bricksId[0])
```

Earlier, in the `__init__`, I define bricks as bricks, which is defined as `Brick(canvas)`. However, the error states:

```
TypeError: 'Brick' object does not support indexing
```

In the answers to the other questions of this subject, I cannot find any that help me access `bricks.bricksId[0]`.

Comment: And what is the full traceback? It appears that `self.bricks.bricksId` is no longer a list if the `self.bricks.bricksId[0]` throws an exception.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Python\Bounce!.py", line 106, in <module>
    ball.draw()
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Python\Bounce!.py", line 47, in draw
    self.hit_brick(pos,self.bricks.bricksId[0])
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Python\Bounce!.py", line 61, in hit_brick
    brick_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.bricks[brickId].id)
TypeError: 'Brick' object does not support indexing

Comment: `self.bricks[brickId]` is **not the same thing** as `self.bricks.bricksId[0]`. Did you mean to use `self.bricks.bricksId[brickId].id` there perhaps?

Comment: How do you initialize `self.bricks`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just fixed that, but I get a new error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Python\Bounce!.py", line 106, in <module>
    ball.draw()
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Python\Bounce!.py", line 47, in draw
    self.hit_brick(pos,self.bricks.bricksId[0])
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Python\Bounce!.py", line 61, in hit_brick
    brick_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.bricks.bricksId[brickId].id)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: @SilasRay In class Ball: In the __init__(self,canvas,paddle,bricks), self.bricks = bricks. bricks is defined as Brick(canvas).

Comment: So `Ball` has `Bricks`?  That sounds like a very... unique encapsulation.  Also, it appears yout `bricksId` list is in fact a list of `int`s, not `Brick`s.  Given that TkInter returns an object ID from `create_rectangle` though, that's not too much of a surprise...

Comment: @JonathanSpirit: sorry, I am not going to debug your code line by line, error by error. I don't know what `canvas` is here, nor what `canvas.create_rectangle()` returns, or what you wanted to do with those rectangles.

Answer (score 45):

In order for the `Brick` object to be indexable, you must implement the methods:

- `__getitem__`
- `__setitem__`
- `__delitem__`

You don't need all of them, only the ones you use.

However, this seems like a case of `self.bricks` being a brick instead of a list of bricks.  A list of bricks is indexable; however, a brick itself is not unless you implement the methods above.

Check [this](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) for reference.

---

In order to be able to call `self.bricks.bricksId[number]` when I needed:

```
def __getitem__(self,index):
    return self.bricks.bricksId[index]

def __setitem__(self,index,value):
    self.bricks.bricksId[index] = value
```