# Class polynomial

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

I am learning classes in Python, I created a class called polynomial, and am trying to add two polynomials, but always get the following error message

> soma.termos[i] = self[i] + other[i]  TypeError: 'Polinomio' object
>   does not support indexing to fix

to fix I created an attribute that is the size of the vector and creates a vector of zeros of size n, but still, the error persists, what is wrong?

```
class Polinomio:

    def __init__ (self, termos = [], n = 0):
        self.termos = termos
        self.n = [0] * n

    def __len__ (self):
        return len(self.termos)

    def __setitem__ (self, i, x):
        self.termos[i] = x

    def __add__ (self, other):
        soma = Polinomio(n = len(self.termos))
        for i in range(len(self.termos)):
            soma.termos[i] = self[i] + other[i]

    def print (self):
        print(self.termos)


p1 = Polinomio([1, 2, 3])
p2 = Polinomio([1, 2, 3])
p2.print()
p3 = Polinomio()
p3 = p1 + p2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Object does not support indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463866/python-object-does-not-support-indexing)

Answer (score 3):

You're not using your internal `termos` property when adding, instead you're trying to index your whole instance which, unsurprisingly, raises an error. Try changing your `__add__` method to:

```
def __add__ (self, other):
    soma = Polinomio(n = len(self.termos))
    for i in range(len(self.termos)):
        soma.termos[i] = self.termos[i] + other[i]
    return soma
```

Or even better:

```
def __add__ (self, other):
    soma = Polinomio(n = len(self.termos))
    for i, v in enumerate(self.termos):
        soma.termos[i] = v + other[i]
    return soma
```

Also, do not initialize your `termos` list in your `__init__` signature as it will always refer to the same list. Instead, declare it as `None` and build it as new whenever it's not passed, i.e.:

```
def __init__ (self, termos = None, n = 0):
    self.termos = termos or []
    self.n = [0] * n
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a method `__getitem__`:

```
def __getitem__(self, i):
     return self.termos[i]
```

And also in your `__add__` function, you instantiate a `Polinomio` by saying `n = len(self.termos)` but your using something called keyword arguments, so it will not actually instantiate a `Polinomio` with `n` as `len(self.termos`, you should instead say `Polinomio([], len(self.termos)` or implement keyword arguments if you want to use that syntax to intstantiate it.